# How to left-pad an integer with zeroes to make it many digits?

Tags: formatting, numbering

A minimal working sample should be give first:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{mynumber}
\makeatletter 
\AtEndDocument{%
    \immediate\write\@auxout{%
        \string\setcounter{mynumber}{\number\value{mynumber}}%
    }%
}
\makeatother
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \stepcounter{mynumber}
}

\begin{document}
the version number is \themynumber.
\end{document}
```

Compiling it with XeLateX, we will get the version number such as 1. Then my **QUESTION** is

- **how to make 1 become 0001 and 23 become 0023 and so on (i.e., four-digit numbers)? Note that I want the format like 0001 but not 0 001 (i e., no unit, no space).**

Comment: There is a `numprint` package additionally but I didn't tested (see sections 3.1 to 3.5 here: ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/numprint/numprint.pdf)

Comment: Ah, good to know. The better option, perhaps. With more possibilities

Comment: I think both solutions will be useful in the future... I don't know how can not find a duplicate on this question... Seems strange to me after these years of tex.se existence!

Comment: It's surprising that this question is so popular...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

with package `siunitx`:

```
the version number is \num[minimum-integer-digits = 4]{\themynumber}.
```

and for Sans Serif

```
\textsf{\num[detect-family,minimum-integer-digits = 4]{\themynumber}}.
```

Comment: This is my favourite.

Comment: Good solution! It's neater than any other ones. But this solution has an disadvantage: we can't change the font of the numbers any more!

Comment: Why can't you change the font??  It is simple!

Comment: \mathrm{} can't work for it by XeLatex. In my document, \mathrm{} should produce old style numbers for \themynumber, but it can't work using your codes.It may be because that the numbers font is deigned by `siunitx` options, for example `mode=text` or `mode=math`. But I think your solution is so good that maybe many other people would like to pick it.

Comment: `\mathrm` will also work ...

Answer (score 15):

Perhaps the fastest (and fully expandable, if that matters) solution, without additional packages:

> ```
> \zeropad{<template>}{<integer>}
> % <template> string of zeros defining desired width of output
> ```

```
\documentclass{article}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\zeropad[2]{%
  \ifnum#2<0\relax%
    {\ensuremath-}\zeropadA{#1}{\the\numexpr#2*-1\relax}%
  \else%
    \zeropadA{#1}{#2}%
  \fi%
}
\def\zeropadA#1#2{%
  \ifnum1#2<1#1
    \zeropadA{#1}{0#2}%
  \else%
    #2%
  \fi%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcounter{mynumber}
\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{%
    \string\setcounter{mynumber}{\themynumber}%
  }%
}
\makeatother
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \stepcounter{mynumber}
}

\begin{document}
the version number is \zeropad{0000}{\themynumber}

this is a negative number: \zeropad{0000}{-\themynumber}

expandibility check: \edef\foo{\zeropad{0000}{-\themynumber}}\foo
\end{document}
```

Comment: Good work! But I can pick only one!

Comment: For whosoever hath ( @egreg ), to him shall be given ... (Gospel of Matthew)

Comment: @Kuttens. Note that my solution does **not** fail if the number get larger than the prescribed width.

Comment: Neat solution.  loved it.

Comment: I like recursive macros.

Answer (score 12):

A fully expandable version

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\padinteger}{mm}
 {
  \int_compare:nNnTF { #2 } < { 0 }
   {
    - \kuttens_padinteger:nn { #1 } { -#2 }
   }
   {
    \kuttens_padinteger:nn { #1 } { #2 }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \kuttens_padinteger:nn
 {
  \prg_replicate:nn { #1 - \tl_count:f { \int_to_arabic:n { #2 } } } { 0 }
  \int_to_arabic:n { #2 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_count:n { f }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% define the macro based on the number of digits you need, here four
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\padfour}[1]{\expandafter\@padfour\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand{\@padfour}[1]{\padinteger{4}{#1}}
\makeatother

\newcounter{mynumber}
\renewcommand{\themynumber}{\padfour{mynumber}}

\makeatletter 
\AtEndDocument{%
    \immediate\write\@auxout{%
        \string\setcounter{mynumber}{\themynumber}%
    }%
}
\makeatother
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \stepcounter{mynumber}
}


\begin{document}

\section{The version number}

Number: \themynumber

\section{Other tests}

\newcounter{test}

\padinteger{4}{\value{test}}

\setcounter{test}{23}

\padinteger{4}{\value{test}}

%\padinteger{4}{12345} % would raise an error

\padinteger{8}{12345}

\setcounter{test}{-123}

$\padinteger{4}{\value{test}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My sol. is expandable too.

Comment: Your macro fails if the number gets larger than the prescribed width. Mine not.

Comment: @AlexG That's a precise choice. The error can be easily removed or changed into a warning.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution, which uses Lua's built-in `string.format` function and sets up a user macro called `\padnum`. Note that the `\padnum` macro is fully expandable.

The default number of padding digits is 4; this can be overridden by supplying the number of padding digits as the optional argument of `\padnum`. The macro handles negative numbers without any issues, and it can be executed in both text mode and math mode.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex

%% Create an external file to contain the Lua code
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{padnum.lua}
function padnum ( digits , n)
-- The "0" term in string.format ensures left-padding with zeroes, as needed:
  tex.sprint ( string.format ( "%0"..digits.."d" , n ) )
end
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\directlua{dofile("padnum.lua")} % load the Lua function
% "\padnum" creates 4-digit numbers by default:
\newcommand\padnum[2][4]{\directlua{padnum(#1,#2)}}

\begin{document}
\newcommand\mynum{23}
\padnum{\mynum}, \padnum[6]{1}, $\padnum[2]{-100000}$, $\padnum{-11}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: A good choice for LuaLatex!

Answer (score 5):

@koleygr Thank you! In fact, I have ever tried your method before you told me but failed. Now I get the right one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{numprint}
\newcounter{mynumber}
\makeatletter 
\AtEndDocument{%
    \immediate\write\@auxout{%
        \string\setcounter{mynumber}{\number\value{mynumber}}%
    }%
}
\makeatother
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \stepcounter{mynumber}
}
\newcommand{\myversionnumber}{\npfourdigitnosep\nplpadding{4}\numprint{\themynumber}}

\begin{document}
the version number is \myversionnumber.
\end{document}
```