# How can I add "frame # of ##" to an animate object?

Tags: animate

I have the following graphics in my document:

`\animategraphics[controls={step},width=\linewidth]{0}{picture}{0}{2}`

that let's the user to view or "scroll" over the three images `picture0.png`, `picture1.png` and `picture2.png`.

Can I add some kind of a label that tells the user which picture is viewed, out of the total images that appear in this `animategraphics` (something like `1/3`, `2/3`, `3/3`)?

Comment: Looking at the `animate` [documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/animate/animate.pdf), `animate` has a `label` options for `\animategraphics` that could possibly be used.

Comment: @LaccaseTVersicolor I don't think it is related to what I asked about it. `label` make the object accesible as js property or method. I am talking about adding a visual label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a visual label, e. g. in the lower right corner, use the `animateinline` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\noindent%
\begin{animateinline}[controls=step]{1}
\multiframe{3}{i=0+1,ii=1+1}{ % zero-based and one-based counters
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{picture\i}%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\raisebox{-\totalheight}{\ii/3}}
}
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

or in the top right corner. Just play with box commands:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\noindent%
\begin{animateinline}[controls=step]{1}
\multiframe{3}{i=0+1,ii=1+1}{ % zero-based and one-based counters
  \raisebox{\depth}{%
    \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{picture\i}}%
    \makebox[0pt][r]{\raisebox{\depth}{\strut\ii/3}}%
  }  
}
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick reply! Can you also explain how to add such a visual label on top of the picture? For example at relative coordinate (0.2,0.4) on the picture? I haven't asked about it in the OP. I was quite general in my question.

Comment: I am terribly sorry, but my pictures I want to include are actually `pic01.png`, `pic02.png`, `pic03.png`, `...`, `pic13.png`, all located at `./figures/` directory. Can you please amend the code for the counters to fit this type of file names?

Comment: You can use my [zero-padding command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/412225):  `\includegraphics{pic\zeropad{00}{\i}}` for two-digits zero-padded numbers.

Comment: Thanks. If the first file is `pic01`, then do I need to make any changes to the `i=0+1` of the `\multiframe` command?

Comment: Ah yes, since the pictures are numbered in a one-based fashion now, the counter `i` isn't needed anymore. You can remove it in the 2nd argument of `\multiframe` and use `\ii` in the `\zeropad` macro.

Comment: Sorry, but what is the argument I need to give for the second argument? Just `i`?

Comment: Only the one-based counter `\ii` is needed. Use it for both, `pic\zeropad{00}{\ii}` and label `\ii/3`. The zero-based counter isn't needed anymore, remove its declaration `i=0+1`.